# PaymentIntent with subscription-based product

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I am creating a paymentIntent in my backend, and I need to know how to attach subscription based products to said paymentIntent so that I can bill the customer on an interval. Every tutorial I have seen uses Stripe checkout instead of Stripe's paymentIntent api. Here is my code:

```
app.post("/create-payment-intent", async (req, res) => {
  const { items } = req.body;
  // Create a PaymentIntent with the order amount and currency. 
  // How do I attach a product to the paymentIntent?
  const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount: calculateOrderAmount(items),
    currency: "usd"
  });
  res.send({
    clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret
  });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the Billing APIs, not a Payment Intent: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/examples